# pom.xml marks "Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0"

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to develop with *Eclipse 2020.6* and *m2e* using *openJDK-11* on *Win10*.
The computer is maintained by IT department having *jre-8* in its *PATH* and I dot have the rights to change that.
I have installed *JDK11* below my user folder.
Changed *eclipse.ini* for *Eclipse* and *toolchain.xml* for commandline *Maven*.
I also checked *Module Dependencies* in *Java Build Path*: *com.sun.tools.jar* is no longer there.

Commandline *Maven* and *Eclipse* are using *JDK11* instead of *jre-8*, except the eclipse-editor for *pom.xml*.
It shows *Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0*
I checked Dependency Hierarchie with the pom.xml editor and it shows that ant:1.10.8 depends on tools:1.8.0. But this information must be wrong, as the project tests and installs correctly.
I guess, the eclipse-editor for *pom.xml* somehow does not use the java libaries pointed to by *eclipse.ini* or *toolchain.xml* or those configured with the project *Build Path*.

*Eclipse Preferences/Maven/User Settings* points to the local repository *.m2\repository* and to the user settings *.m2\settings.xml*. I also copied *toolchain.xml* to .m2, but without solving the problem.

Please note that I do not have any problem running *Maven* from within *Eclipse*. It works as expected. My problem is, that errors are flagged within *Eclipse* where there is none.

**Why does the *pom.xml* editor in *Eclipse* complains about *tools.jar:1.8.0*?** How can I make *m2e* not using java from the PATH but using *JDK11* installation for my developments in *Eclipse*?

Comment: I am facing similar issue with the same version of eclipse. in my case I'm happy using java 8. But it still try to get tools.jar from .m2e repository. Any solution?